# Need help converting encryption logic from Js to Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I am trying to re-create a code snippet from JS to Java, but the outputs are different. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code snippet from JS:

```js
var randomKey = 2116781760886580;

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomKey);

var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomKey);

var encrypt = CryptoJS.AES
    .encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("Text to encrypt"), key,
        {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

var out = btoa(encrypt);   //SGpJSWhDUXNmMEMzSk0vbmovaGZyQT09
```

The following is the Java code snippet:

```java
String randomKey = "2116781760886580";

String plainText = "Text to encrypt";

byte[] keyBytes = randomKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);

SecretKeySpec sKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"AES");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey, ivSpec);

byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String out = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);    //HjIIhCQsf0C3JM/nj/hfrA==
```

Comment: Your key looks like a number in JS, while it is a string in Java (at least the type says so, as the code is not valid Java). Could that be the difference?

Comment: I think, you encrypt two times in your js code.

    CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("Text to encrypt") ....

But in java code, you encrypt one time.

Comment: The bug is in the CryptoJS code. `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` returns a `CipherParams` object that encapsulates various data, including the ciphertext. I don't know what `btoa` does with this object, but it doesn't return the Base64 encoded ciphertext. You can get it with `encrypt.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)` or shorter with `encrypt.toString()` and it corresponds to the Base64 encoded ciphertext of the Java code. By the way, using the key as IV is generally insecure.

Comment: @marstran I double checked that in JS by printing the word array using string and number types, both results were the same.

Comment: @Topaco Ok, I am trying to re-create the same logic in Java, from an already existing implementation in CryptoJs.

Comment: You have to Base64 encode in the Java code a 2nd time: `String out2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(out.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` Then you get the result of the CryptoJS code. Of course this is a pointless implementation.

Comment: @Topaco Great!! Thank you, yes that solved it. Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I have posted an answer.

Comment: AES uses binary keys - you should provide a binary key. If you use a String with 16 digits as key (as you do in you code), you are effectively redusing you key to ~55 bits of entropy. This give you the same level of key length used with single DES (56 bit). Single DES was broken more than 20 yeas ago. Don't make new code that is broken from the start.

Comment: Thank you @EbbeM.Pedersen, for pointing this out. When I write something from the scratch, I will definitely keep this in mind. This however was a try to recreate a piece of code in Java which was already implemented somewhere else. Thanks once again to all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` returns a [`CipherParams`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output) object that encapsulates several data, in particular the ciphertext. If the `CipherParams` object is passed to [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa#syntax), it is first implicitly converted to a string using `toString()` which returns the Base64 encoded ciphertext of the `CipherParams` object by default, at least if no salt is involved as in this case. Together with the Base64 encoding of `btoa()`, the ciphertext is therefore Base64 encoded *twice*.

So that the Java code provides the same result as the JavaScript code, the ciphertext must therefore also be Base64 encoded twice, which is done e.g. with the following addition:

```
String out2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(out.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Note that the redundant Base64 encoding is actually useless and only increases the amount of data ([Base64 has 33% overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)). Also, using the key as IV is generally insecure, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16161).